# Multiple Selection Auto Complete Search Functionality - Angular Material Chips

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I am using Angular 7 & Angular Material for fetching the user name from an api.
For that I have used angular material chips. Here is the link, I am following:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/jemmxnqdyro?file=app%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts

But the problem is that currently I am fetching the data from an array. What i really need is to fetch the user name from this api: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users. What I am confused is how to use angular material chips and how to fetch data.

Could you please help me to implement the same since I am new to angular.

It would be really helpful if someone can show a demo on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use `ObjectMapper` to convert your `JSON` and map this `JSON`with a `POJO` to get all the `userName` in the given `JSON`.

Comment: @PawanTiwari: Could you please show me a demo/sample code for this? I am new to angular. It would be really helpful.

Comment: I haven't used material-chips but have had some experience with creating and consuming API calls in angular 6. Maybe [this](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-httpclient/) tutorial could be of help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**HERE IS A WORKING STACKBLITZ EXAMPLE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fcbmzy-nrauuk) as per your request.
What you should do now:
1- Create a model for your data and use it in the Service and the subscribe (you can see I'm using 'any' in my subscribe method.
2- Change variable names accordingly (usernameCtrl, allUsernames instead of allFruits etc..)
3- If you wish to remove an item from the autocomplete options if it's already selected, remove it (remove method in ts) from the allUsernames array (now allFruits) and add it the the usernames array, make sure to do the opposite when the user chooses to delete the chip, you can play around with the other methods to make your desired functionalities.

To apply array changes instantly to your autocomplete, don't forget to `this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);`

Comment: Just a clarification, since the service returns Observable, then why we are not using here?

Comment: One issue i faced is when I type some random input, it also gets selected and saved. How can I remove that? Any suggestion for the same?

Comment: We are using the observable by subscribing to it in the ngOnInit

Comment: Remove the add method from component, it will disable entering text without selection.

Comment: Thanks again. Is it possible to remove already selected user from dropdown section? Right now when i click on input even though user gets selected, on another select, selected user is still showing in dropdown section. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192573/discussion-between-vishnu-and-ala).